# Extending a class with a constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor

Hey guys i have a class called client. i want to seperate its function into two subclasses: ClientListner and ClientSender. the client it self has a constructor that looks like this:

**Client constructor**

```
public Client(Socket socket, PrintWriter pw, Scanner input, MainGui mg){
    this.mg = mg;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.input = input;
    this.pw = pw;
}
```

When ever my two other classes extends this client Eclipse ask me to implement the construcktor and auto generate the following:

**ClientSender auto generated constructor**

```
public ClientSender(Socket socket, PrintWriter pw, Scanner input, MainGui mg) {
    super(socket, pw, input, mg);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

And so when i am in my Gui and want to make a new Clientlistner i have to pass all of these information isnt there a way to avoid this? and if so how?

Comment: Just define a 0-arg constructor in your `Client` class, and then you can use any constructor in all your derived classes. But mind you, you would be at a risk to initializing your base class fields to null

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass anything in the construvtor you can have a `no-arg` constructor in your parent class.

Edited:
In your `Client` class just write this code it is a `no-arg` constructor:

```
public Client(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use `ClientSender` to handle all outgoing content and `ClientReceiver` to handle all incoming content of a `Client`, they should be different classes that take the socket's `OutputStream` and `InputStream` once the Client is created. So, they should be members in the Client class than being subtypes of Client.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the variables in the Client constructor so it only contains variable that both ClientListner and ClientSender uses.